# Intravenous therapy - why does blood come out of my body once the fluid is depleted?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, pressure, flow, equilibrium

The other day I wasn't feeling so well so I visited a doctor. He recommended that I take a break and get intravenous therapy so I did. I laid on a bed and the nurse inserted a needle into my left arm which was connected to the pack of liquid containing vitamins. I soon fell asleep.

More than half an hour later I woke up. The pack was practically empty. However blood was slowly flowing out of my vein. I frantically called the nurse, who apologized for not catching it earlier.

I thought the sole factor that delivers the fluid to my body was gravity, since the pack is hung in the air much higher than my arm. But given that the direction of flow reversed once the pack was emptied, my assumption is probably false.

My new theory is that the vitamins are delivered because the pack's pressure is higher than my vein's when there is enough liquid in the pack. However this still doesn't explain why I started losing blood as when the two sides' pressure reaches parity all movement should stop. Since the pack's initial pressure was higher, There should be no change of direction until reaching equilibrium.

Why did I lose blood and are there any precautions I can take to prevent this incident in the future?

Comment: Once the pressure equalizes you can still have diffusion of blood into the tubing (and vice versa). Our eyes are well attuned to the sight of blood, so it does not take much red coloring in the tube to seem like a lot of blood.

Comment: And don't forget that your heart is pumping, so the pressure in the vein will regularly exceed that in the bag/tube outside your body.

Comment: *are there any precautions I can take to prevent this incident in the future* That's something you should be asking the medical staff (doctors, nurses, etc), rather than random physics enthusiasts

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it belongs on the [Medical Sciences Stack Exchange](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/)